# How to pass multiple arguments to a function from module instead of command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this script: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

And I can run it from command line without problem like this (for example):

python3 upload_youtube.py --file file_to_upload.mp4

I want to call this module from another, so I write this simple script:

```
import upload_youtube        
upload_youtube.initialize_upload(['youtube', 'options'])
```

But when I execute it I get this error:

```
TypeError: initialize_upload() missing 1 required positional argument: 'options'
```

I try using the argument directly in the call, like this:

```
upload_youtube.initialize_upload(['youtube', "--file 'video.mp4'"])
```

But it doens works... I get the same error, so I I doing some wrong, but I don't know what is it.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `upload_youtube.py`?

Comment: The module is available here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#python

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what `upload_youtube.py` or the methods within are (I didn't see that module anywhere in the link you included), we can only guess.

As such, my guess is that the method you're calling is expecting arguments as separate items, not a list, which is why you're missing an argument. As such, try:

`upload_youtube.initialize_upload("youtube", "options")`

and see where that gets you.

Comment: Hi @Cailean and thank you for your reply

First, you can see the complete module (upload_youtube.py) at the bottom of the mentioned link. But here you have the direct link to the python code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#python

Second, I try your suggestion and now the error os:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keywords'`

But keyword attribute it is not neccesary, how could I pass "file" argument throug the "options" argument?